# the "microsoft ACE.OLEDB.12.5" provider is not registered on the local > machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I made small application to import excel files 2007+ to `datagridview` after 
copy the `.exe` file from the development pc to the working pc when I press button to load excel file I get this error message

I tried to install `AccessDatabaseEngine`but that is wont help

any idea what is going on ?

**note** working environment is `windows 7` and `windows xp SP2`

> the "microsoft ACE.OLEDB.12.5" provider is not registered on the local
>   machine
>
> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
>   provider is not registered on the local machine.    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection,
>   ConnectionState& originalState)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable
>   dataTable)    at LoadExcel.Form1.LoadExcel(String FilePath)    at
>   LoadExcel.Form1.GetFilesList()    at
>   LoadExcel.Form1.B_Load_Excel_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8762 (QFE.050727-8700)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- LoadExcel
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Internet/Desktop/LoadExcel.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5491 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8770 (QFE.050727-8700)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5495 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Data
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8762 (QFE.050727-8700)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8773 (QFE.050727-8700)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Transactions
>       Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5483 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
>
> ************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
>   with debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

Comment: You need the exact match between the 64bit and 32bit of this provider against the target platform or your own application

Comment: @Steve in my application I have set the platform target to any pc

Comment: It is a convoluted matter. AnyCPU (with Prefer 32bit) means that your app runs in 32bit even on 64bit OS. So you need to install the AccessDatabaseEngine for 32bit (but if you have already installed Office with 64bit then you need to remove the prefer 32 bit or install Office 32bit) I suggest you to search this site for the exact error message. There are a lot of duplicates.

Comment: By the way, I am unaware of any 12.5 version of this provider. Are you sure about this number? I thougth the last one was version 12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quoting @Steve comment which was the answer of my question 
the `AccessDatabaseEngine` was correct and according to my operating system and the `Microsoft office` too is correct version, but I have to change my project platform from `64bit` to `AnyCPU`

It is a convoluted matter. `AnyCPU (with Prefer 32bit)` means that your app runs in `32bit` even on `64bit OS`. So you need to install the `AccessDatabaseEngine` for `32bit` (but if you have already installed `Office with 64bit` then you need to remove the prefer 32 bit or install Office 32bit) I suggest you to search this site for the exact error message. There are a lot of duplicates.

By the way, I am unaware of any 12.5 version of this provider. Are you sure about this number? I thougth the last one was version 12.0